# How can `document.execCommand` be unit tested?

Tags: mocha.js, sinon, jsdom

I'm trying to write unit tests for word-processor-like operations such as applying a list to a text node, but I found that `document.execCommand` is not available to `jsdom`, so I'm stumped as to how I could unit test the following operation:

```js
document.getElementById('run').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.execCommand("insertorderedlist");
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Foo</div>
<button id="run">Select "Foo" then Click</button>
```

Comment: rebelliard, did you get it working? Trying to figure out if I can mock this up somehow...

Comment: @Alexandra nop!

Answer (score 5):

I ended up having to mock the `document.execCommand` explicitly:

```
// test-mocks.js
global.document.execCommand = function execCommandMock() { };
```

And then feeding my mocks into mocha directly:

```
"specs": "mocha --require @babel/register --require jsdom-global/register --require ignore-styles --require test-mocks.js ./path/to/tests.spec.js"
```

Comment: I ended up with the same thing with jest + react-testing-library : add a `document.execCommand = jest.fn()` on the top of my testing file and `expect(document.execCommand).toHabeBeenCalledWith('copy')`.